# how to reduce fps of incoming stream by dropping frames in C

Tags: c, frame-rate

I've got a stream of jpegs with 30FPS. I want to reduce the fps by dropping packets.

I can do 15FPS by dropping every second package like: `if(frameCount % 2) continue;`

20 FPS is also achievable with `if(frameCount % 3) continue;`

I'm struggling to find a condition to adapt this to all FPS.
Like 5FPS? Theoretically I have to drop 25 FPS, but how do I manage this, so that the frames have  approx. the same duration between them?

Comment: You may depend on time, in psuedocode: `timestamp = get_time(); period = 1/required_fps; while (...) { if (get_time() - timestamp < period) continue; timestamp = get_time();  /* do stuff */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you want to drop frames so that you output 15 for every 30 you get as input, you're outputting 0.5 frames per input frame. Similarly, for a 30->20 dropping, you're outputting 0.67 frames per input frame.

So, as a trivial solution, you could keep a count of the fractional number of frames you're expected to output, and output a single frame when that count goes to one or above.

As a rough sketch, with just an integer loop taking place of the frames:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double sum = 0;
    double rate = argc >= 2 ? atoi(argv[1]) / 30.0 : 0.5;

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        sum += rate;
        if (sum >= 1) {
            sum -= 1;
            /* pretend we output this frame */
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Run as `foo 20` or something like that to get 20 out of 30 printed.

Or approximately 20 out of 30. That's not entirely accurate because of rounding issues, and the fact that 2/3 can't be represented exactly as binary floating point value. You could modify it to count with rationals instead, so could present 20/30 exactly.

Of course, any divider that doesn't divide 30 exactly will produce jittery output.

---

For 5 FPS, you could just use modulo again, since 5 divides 30 exactly. Just invert the sense of the test from dropping a fraction to accepting a fraction, e.g. `if (framenumber % 5 == 0) { accept frame }`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!